# Does obtaining Lie algebras via differentiation work for a general Lie group?

Tags: lie-algebras, lie-groups

I noticed that the characterizations of the Lie algebras of matrix Lie groups can be obtained by differentiation. For example:

$$O(n) = XX^t = \mathbb{1} \implies \mathfrak{o}(n) = X + X^t = \mathbb{0}$$

$$SO(n) = XX^t = \mathbb{1},\; \text{det}(X) = 1 \implies \mathfrak{so}(n) = X + X^t = \mathbb{0},\; tr(X)=0$$

but it works also for $U(n), SU(n), Sl(n,\mathbb{K})$.

Does this work for a general Lie group?

Comment: Yes I know this, but I was wondering if there exists a theorem stating this in a formal way

Comment: I guess you'd have to be more specific about what you want. I admit that this is a hard thing to do, at times!

Comment: I would like to know if there exist a theorem saying:
Given a Lie group described by a set of equations, the Lie algebra is described by taking the derivatives of those equation

Comment: Maybe you're looking for the idea that the Lie algebra of $G$ is the tangent space at the identity.  It's discussed here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_group#The_Lie_algebra_associated_with_a_Lie_group

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The matrix groups can be defined as regular level sets of functions $f: GL(n) \to M$ where $M = \mathbb R$ (e.g. for $SL(n)$) or $M = n\times n$ matrices (e.g. for $O(n)$).  In general, if you have a map $f: M \to N$ and $y \in N$ is a regular value then $f^{-1}(y)$ is a submanifold and $T_xf^{-1}(y) = \ker df_x : T_x M \to T_y N$.  So in the case of $O(n)$ for example you're differentiating the function $X \mapsto XX^t$ at the identity to see that its Lie algebra (identifiable with $T_e O(n)$ is skew-symmetric matrices.

Comment: I just got to the same solution by myself, just before reading your answer. In any case thanks!

Comment: Great answer Eric! I know this is a bit late of a comment but couldn't we do the same thing for the set of upper triangular matrices $B\in GL(n)$? What would be the map $f$ in this case? Could matrix groups be defined as regular level sets of functions only in the real setting or is this true in the complex setting as well?

Answer (score 6):

A Lie group is also a differentiable manifold; in particular we can define its tangent space at the identity.  Intuitively, the tangent space is the set of directions $v$ such that if you start at the identity in $G$ and move infinitesimally in direction $v$, you stay in $G$.

Let's say that $G$ is defined by the vanishing of some differentiable function $f$: so $G = \{ X: f(X)=0\}$.  The tangent space consists of matrices $M$ such that $f(I + \epsilon M) =0$ to first order in $\epsilon$: using the Taylor expansion and neglecting higher terms, what we want is that $df_I(M)=0$ where $df_I$ is the total derivative at the identity.  Elements of the kernel of the total derivative are exactly those vectors which can be realised as $\gamma'(0)$ for some differentiable $\gamma: (-1,1)\to G$: the usual definition of tangent space is the equivalence classes of such functions $\gamma$ under the relation $\gamma_1\sim \gamma_2$ iff $\gamma_1'(0)=\gamma_2'(0)$.

The Lie algebra associated to $G$ has as its underlying vector space the tangent space at the identity, so it really is obtained by differentiating and setting the total derivative equal to zero.

Looking at your $O(n)$ example, the "$f$" is $f(X)=XX^t-I$.  To find the total derivative at the identity, we ought to have $f(I+\epsilon M) = I + \epsilon df_I(M) +$ higher order terms.  To order one in epsilon we have $f(I+\epsilon M)= \epsilon (M + M^t)$, so the total derivative at the identity is $M+M^t$. The vanishing of this is exactly the condition you gave for being in the Lie algebra of $O(n)$.